# Is it possible to use column value being updated to update another column within a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

I have below table `Course` which has 3 columns `Student_Name`, `Joining_Date` and `Batch_Number`. `Batch_Number` is calculated based on `Joining_Date` by concatenating Month, Date and Year part from `Joining_Date`.

One entry in database would look like something:

```
Aman | 01/08/2016 | 08012016
```

I want to update `Joining_Date` to say 01/08/2017 and want to update `Batch_Number` based on `Joining_Date` in just one query.

I am able to achieve it in two steps:

First step:

```
UPDATE Course 
SET Joining_Date =  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date)
WHERE Student_Name = 'Aman'
```

Second step:

```
UPDATE Course 
SET Batch_Number = CONCAT(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MM,Joining_Date)), 2), RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(DD,Joining_Date)), 2), DATEPART(YYYY,Joining_Date))
WHERE Student_Name = 'Aman'
```

I want to achieve the above thing in one step. So while trying:

```
UPDATE Course 
SET Joining_Date =  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date),
    Batch_Number = CONCAT(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MM,Joining_Date)), 2), RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(DD,Joining_Date)), 2), DATEPART(YYYY,Joining_Date))
WHERE Student_Name = 'Aman'
```

It is not updating `Batch_Number` and it uses the old value of `Joining_Date` so `Batch_Number` remains the same.

Is it possible to update `Joining_Date` and `Batch_Number` in one shot?

Early response will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance readers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, use the same expression for `Joining_Date` column (`DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date)`)in your `UPDATE` statement for other column as well instead of the column itself like

```
UPDATE Course 
SET Joining_Date = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date),
Batch_Number = CONCAT(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date))) ....
WHERE Student_Name = 'Aman'
```

Comment: It works guys! Don't know why it didn't come to my mind before posting this lengthy question here.

Thank you guys You rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Course SET Joining_Date = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date), 
Batch_Number = CONCAT(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date))), 2), 
RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date))), 2), 
DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Joining_Date))) 
WHERE Student_Name = 'Aman'
```

Comment: It works guys! Don't know why it didn't come to my mind before posting this lengthy question here.

Thank you guys You rock!

Answer (score 0):

## 1 CTE

```
 DECLARE @course TABLE 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Joining_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Batch_Number VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @course(Joining_Date)
VALUES ('20150401'), ('19951121'), ('20000229')

;with cteCourse as
(
    SELECT
      DATEADD(YEAR, 1, cr.Joining_Date) as Joining_Date_new,
      cr.Joining_Date,
      cr.Batch_Number
    FROM @course cr
    --WHERE cr.Student_Name = 'Aman'
)
UPDATE cr SET
    Joining_Date =  Joining_Date_new,
    Batch_Number = CONCAT(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MM,Joining_Date_new)), 2), RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(DD,Joining_Date_new)), 2), DATEPART(YYYY,Joining_Date_new))
FROM cteCourse cr


SELECT * FROM @course
ORDER BY 1
```

## 2 OLD-SCHOOL VAR TRICK

```
DECLARE @course TABLE 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Joining_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Batch_Number VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @course(Joining_Date)
VALUES ('20150401'), ('19951121'), ('20000229')

DECLARE @Joining_Date_new DATE

UPDATE cr SET
    @Joining_Date_new = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, cr.Joining_Date),
    Joining_Date =  @Joining_Date_new,
    Batch_Number = CONCAT(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MM,@Joining_Date_new)), 2), RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(DD,@Joining_Date_new)), 2), DATEPART(YYYY,@Joining_Date_new))
FROM @course cr


SELECT * FROM @course
ORDER BY 1
```

both ways same result:

[image]

Comment: It works guys! Don't know why it didn't come to my mind before posting this lengthy question here.

Thank you guys You rock!

Answer (score 0):

You could just very easily add a **computed column** to your table, based on  `Joining_Date`, and do away with having to update a second column in your trigger.....

Do this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Course
ADD BatchNo AS FORMAT(Joining_Date, 'MMddyyyy')
```

This will format the "joining date" to day-month-year - as you want it - and this will be kept up to date and correct all the time. So in your trigger, you just simply change the `Joining_Date` and bingo - you're done! `BatchNo` will be **automagically** be correct after you've updated your `Joining_date` column...